# Android studio - How to use directly the terminal from java method?

Tags: java, android, bash, sh

I am new to Android development, and I try to access to the internal terminal (/bin/bash, ...) of Android phone using a java method.

Do you know if such java method exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Runtime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html) and [Process](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) to achieve your task.

```
private static String executeCommand(String command) {
    Process process = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        String line;
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line + "\n";
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (process != null)
                process.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Where command is any available terminal commands like PING 8.8.8.8